# Is a static member variable common for all C# generic instantiations?

Tags: c#, generics, static-variables

In C# I have a generic class:

```
public class MyGeneric<ParameterClass> where ParameterClass: MyGenericParameterClass, new() {
    public static int Variable;
}
```

Now in C++ if I instantiated a templated class with different parameters each complete class would get it's own `Variable`, so [I just can't say](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3198249/57428)

```
MyGeneric.Variable = 1; // invalid in C++
```

in C++, but seems like I can do so in C#.

I'd like to clarify...

If I have a generic with a static member variable is that variable shared among all generic instantiations?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Section 25.1.4 of the ECMA C# Language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm)

> A static variable in a generic class declaration is **shared amongst
>   all instances of the same closed constructed type (§26.5.2), but is
>   not shared amongst instances of different closed constructed types.**
>   These rules apply regardless of whether the type of the static
>   variable involves any type parameters or not.

You may see this blog post: [Static fields in generic classes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gusperez/archive/2005/08/09/449363.aspx) by [Gus Perez](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/gus%20perez/)

You can't do that in C# as well.

```
MyGeneric.Variable = 1;
```

Consider the following example from ECMA Language Specification.

```
class C<V>
{
    static int count = 0;
    public C()
    {
        count++;
    }
    public static int Count
    {
        get { return count; }
    }
}
class Application
{
    static void Main()
    {
        C<int> x1 = new C<int>();
        Console.WriteLine(C<int>.Count);  // Prints 1 
        C<double> x2 = new C<double>();
        Console.WriteLine(C<double>.Count); // Prints 1 
        Console.WriteLine(C<int>.Count);  // Prints 1 
        C<int> x3 = new C<int>();
        Console.WriteLine(C<int>.Count);  // Prints 2 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
MyGeneric<MyClass>.Variable
MyGeneric<MyOther>.Variable
```

These two are different static variables treated like separate classes.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not.  Generic types can be "open" or "closed."  An open type is one like `List<T>` where the type parameter isn't defined; `List<int>` is a closed type.

Essentially, the open type isn't treated as a proper "Type" by the runtime - only the closed versions are true types.  So, `MyGeneric<int>` and `MyGeneric<string>` are two entirely different types, and thus have their own instances of the static variable.

This is made more obvious by the fact that you *can't* call your static member in the way you suggest: `MyGeneric.Variable` will not compile in C#.

This console application code illustrates it quite simply:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test<int>.i = 2;
        Test<string>.i = 8;

        Console.WriteLine(Test<int>.i);   // would write "8" if the fields were shared
        Console.WriteLine(Test<string>.i);
        // Console.WriteLine(Test.i); // does not compile
        // Console.WriteLine(Test<>.i); // does not compile
    }
}

class Test<T>
{
    public static int i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not shared.

Each `MyGeneric<T>` class will resolve to a different runtime type, for each possibility of `T`.

Please check that there is no non-generic `MyGeneric` class with the `Variable` static member.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, the answer to your question is no. However, what you can do is use a parent class to your generic class, and have your static variable in there. Any method you need to call could be abstracted into that parent class.

```
abstract class MyBase
{
    protected static MyBase selected;

    public abstract void Deselect();
}
```

```
class MyGeneric<T> : MyBase
{
    public void Select()
    {
        if (selected != null)
        {
            if (selected != this)
            {
                selected.Deselect();
            }
        }
        selected = this;
        //...
    }

    public override void Deselect()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```