# Static member shared across template specializations

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Given the following class template, is there any way to have the field `a` to be the same across all specializations (i.e. `A<int>::a` is the same lvalue as `A<std::string>::a`)?

```
template<class T>
class A final {
private:
    static int a;
};
```

Comment: Missing `;` at the end of the class declaration.

Comment: @user2296177 thanks, fixed.

Comment: Yes, just inherit from a non-templated base class which would store the static member.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sharing static members between template instantiations? (impossible?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198249/sharing-static-members-between-template-instantiations-impossible)

Answer (score 4):

Simply inherit (privately) from a non-template and move the `static` there:

```
class ABase {
protected:
    static int a;
}; 

int ABase::a;

template<class T>
class A final : private ABase 
{ };
```

Comment: The only issue that I can see with this is that anyone can inherit from `ABase`, is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Isn't `final` redundant here?

Comment: @Nicholas Yeah - but is it worth the effort? Just hide the base somewhere.

Comment: @NicholasMertin Making the base class constructor private and the template class a friend should prevent unintended inheritance.

Comment: @ΔλЛ Not if you don't want anything inheriting from `A`.

Comment: OK, just realized that's what OP wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to those of you who suggested a non-templated base class. A similar solution that I found that removes the issue of an API consumer inheriting from the base class is to have it as a final class with the templated class declared as a friend:

```
class A_Data final {
private:
    static int a;

    template<class T>
    friend class A;
};

template<class T>
class A final {
};
```