# c++ initialization of static object in class declaration

Tags: c++, static-members

I have a C++ class (class1) with a static object of another class (class2) as a private member.

I know upon using the program I will have to initialize the static object, I can use a default constructor for this (undesired value).

Is it possible to initialize the static object to my desired value only once, and only if I create an object of the containing class (class1)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't use a class constructor to initialize a static member.  Constructors are called every time a new instance of the object is created, but statics are only initialized once.

Comment: @JohnDibling yes you can if you add a check.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: In your code below, `Bptr = new B(arguments, to, constructor);` isn't an initialization.  The initialization is `B* A::Bptr = nullptr;`.

Comment: @JohnDibling ah, you are right, terminology mistake.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes.

```
// interface

class A {

    static B b;
};

// implementation

B A::b(arguments, to, constructor); // or B A::b = something;
```

However, it will be initialised even if you don't create an instance of the `A` class. You can't do it any other way unless you use a pointer and initialise it once in the constructor, but that's probably a bad design.

IF you **really want to** though, here's how:

```
// interface

class A {
    A() { 
        if (!Bptr)
            Bptr = new B(arguments, to, constructor);

        // ... normal code
    }

    B* Bptr;
};

// implementation

B* A::Bptr = nullptr;
```

However, like I said, that's most likely a bad design, and it has multithreading issues.

Comment: ok I see what you mean. Yea, the pointer thing wont work cause I can gonna be making many objects of class A

Comment: @bryansammon it doesn't matter how many you make, I will write an example.

Comment: Thanks alot, you think thats a bad design habit?

Comment: @bryansammon well, it of course depends on your situation, but I think there are more situations in which it's bad design than there are in which it's good design. I can't think of a situation in which you'd want a new seperate single object to appear after you create one of those objects. You get to make the final decision though.

Comment: @bryansammon actually nevermind, that way wouldn't work, my bad.

Comment: Cool, I really apprecaite your help

Comment: For some remarks on the threading issues, impact on API design, and C++11 you might find this related question interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507973/how-to-mitigate-user-facing-api-effect-of-shared-members-in-templated-classes

Comment: You don't have to do the test in the constructor; any factory function will do.  And if the object being constructed is mutable, you're not introducing any additional threading issues; you'll need a lock to access it, regardless of what you do.  (On the other hand, truly mutable objects with static lifetime are rarely a good idea.  Although there are exceptions.)

Comment: @JamesKanze actually I think you do have to do the test in the constructor, since what he wanted is to have the `B` object constructed _only if an `A` is constructed_. I was going to provide an example of returning a reference to a `static` variable inside a function, however that would make it where the `B` would be constructed when you first called the function, even if an `A` hadn't been constructed yet.

Comment: If the factory function is only called from non-static members of `A`, that should do the trick.

Comment: @JamesKanze From what I gathered, the `B` is not only for use by `A`.

Comment: @SethCarnegie That's what I understood as well.  Otherwise, a singleton would do the trick.