# export static member for another dll

Tags: c++, templates, dll, dllexport

I have a dll that exports some functions so a second dll can use them. Both dll's are loaded by a main. Now I have the problem with exporting a data member inside the dll.

I have a template class looking like this (**temp.hpp**):

```
template<typename T>
class __declspec(dllexport) base {
public:
    static T buf;
    static void do_smt(T val);
};

template<typename T>
void base<T>::do_smt(T val) {
    base<T>::buf = val;
}
```

A second class which inherits from the template class (**dll.h**). This header is shared between the 2 dll's.

```
#include "temp.hpp"

class __declspec(dllexport) child
    : public base <int> {};
```

And the **dll.cpp** looks like:

```
#include "dll.h"

base<int> inter;
int base<int>::buf;
```

There are some more other function, so I tried to reduce it down to the basics.

This compiles and creates a .lib and a .dll. Now I have another project which is compiled with the .lib. The main is loading both dll's, so the second dll could use **`do_smt`** (which is working if I remove the `static int buf`). But I get an error that my buf is unresolved.

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static int base<struct int>::buf" (?buf@?$base@Uint@@@@2HA)  module.obj
```

I also tried something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2220990/1810087)

```
template <class T>
int base<T>::buf;

int base<int>::buf;
```

but got the same error.

Everything is working without my static buf.

**How can I make my buf static buf exported in my dll.cpp (dll.dll) that my other dll's could use it by the static do_smt method?**

I'm using vs2012.

### edit:

dumpbin /exports dll.dll returns:

```
File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for dll.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    520D5353 time date stamp Fri Aug 16 00:16:51 2013
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           5 number of functions
           5 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 000613E9 ??4?$base@Uint@@@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z = @ILT+17380(??4?$base@Uint@@@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z)
          2    1 0005F2BF ??4child@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z = @ILT+8890(??4child@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z)
          3    2 0014F594 ?buf@?$base@Uint@@@@2HA = ?buf@?$base@Uint@@@@2HA (public: static int base<int>::buf)
          4    3 0005D90B ?getdllDLLInit@@YAJPAUPlugInHeader@@@Z = @ILT+2310(?getdllDLLInit@@YAJPAUPlugInHeader@@@Z)
          5    4 0005F0BC dllDLL = @ILT+8375(_dllDLL)

  Summary

        4000 .data
        4000 .idata
       29000 .rdata
        9000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
       C6000 .text
       5C000 .textbss
        1000 .tls
```

seems that buf is inside the dll.

### edit 2:

The main is not written by me and i don't have the code. Also the main is not really loading the dll.dll. it is loading the library with **LoadLibrary** for checking some information (by getdllDLLInit (maybe bad named)) and *unload* it again. The dll.dll is in the root directory of the exe. It will be loaded automatically by windows if necessary. The other dll's are loaded explicitly by the .exe by using **LoadLibrary**.

My first try was without any classes or templates, just gobal functions and it worked. After, I've created a template class putting the functions in. The reason is, dll.dll will be reused with some other type's, so I don't have to rewrite to much (just change the inheritance `class __declspec(dllexport) child: public base <some_other_type> {};` and redefine the statics...) i could rewrite all again and again but this will violate against the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.

### edit 3:

After willj adviced me to try it without the template, i found something new. The problem is while the method is inside the header and not inside the cpp. If I just rewrite the template

```
template<typename T>
class __declspec(dllexport) base {...};
```

to

```
class __declspec(dllexport) baseInt {...};
```

it still won't work, but if I seperate the methods from the header and move them in to a cpp (in my case it's more important to move `base::buf` to the cpp) it works. I think the problem is, even if the base::buf member is compiled correctly into dll.dll, the other project can't find the definition **during** compile time even it is defined in the lib. I don't know if this is a bug in msvc or it's correct behaviour. I though by inheriting from the base with a specific type would be do it.

Since I want to use a template and just 1 (global) header I start thinking this problem may be unresolveable.

### edit 4:

commands:

- compile

> /FR"Debug\" /GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"my include path's" /Zi /Gm- /Od /Fd"Debug\vc110.pdb" /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_WIN32_WINDOWS=0x0501" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_USRDLL" /D "NOMINMAX" /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" /D "_WINDLL" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\test.pch"

- link

> /OUT:"Debug\test.dll" /MANIFEST /PDB:"Debug\test.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE:NO "dll.lib" "Winmm.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /IMPLIB:"Debug\test.lib" /DEBUG /DLL /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"Debug\test.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Debug\test.dll.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"D:/prg/svn/branches/DLL/Debug" /LIBPATH:"D:\prg\svn\trunk\LIBS\boost\1.53.0\lib\msvc-32bit" /TLBID:1

Comment: What does the export table show for your `dll.dll`?

Comment: @greatwolf i edited m question.   at angry ferret thx for correcting.

Comment: That's interesting. Can you also add how main is being built? Specifically what the compile and link commands look like.

Comment: did you already try to the same thing but replace `template<typename T> class base` with `class baseInt` and `base<int>` with `baseInt`?Just to rule out templates as a factor.

Comment: @greatwolf my comment was to long, so a new edit :) i also will give a try for willj's advice.

Comment: If main is using `LoadLibrary` and probably `GetProcAddress` to get symbols from dll.dll then it should not be pulling in 'dll.h' and using any of 'dll.h' definitions. Also, how would `LoadLibrary` even work given how the symbols are mangled in the dll? This would probably make more sense building main with dll's import library.

Comment: @willj i tried it, and found something out. please see my **edit 3**.

Comment: @greatwolf the main doesn't pull in dll.h. it doesn't even know dll.* is even exist while compile time, it only know about dll.dll while runtime (it loads **all** libraries in the root and unload them again). also the main don't have to know about dll.*  . i really can't change the main. i just know it works through some tests.

Comment: @itwasntpete how does `module.obj` fit into this? That seems to be the translation unit trying to use `base<int>::buf`. Is module's source compiled and linked as part of main's project also?

Comment: @greatwolf no it is the compilation of the second dll which should access the methods.

Comment: @greatwolf first thx for your help. sorry but maybe my question is not asked well. my dll.dll is compiling, but my second dll which is using the methods and members isn't compiling and results with the errormessage. i figure out that it is so while the template is compiled in both project's, and even if `buf` is existing in dll.dll and dll.lib my second dll (let's call it module.*) can't find it while compiling. looking in to the binary, dll.dll contains buf, and module.obj contains it marked as export (like all methods from base) like i was expecting.

Comment: @itwasntpete Are you sure when the second dll gets linked you're passing the first dll's import library to the linker? Just to rule out obvious causes, can you show what the compile and link commands look like for the second dll?

Comment: @greatwolf yes i'm sure, but see my edit 4.

Comment: Remove all dllexport and dllimport stuff from templates, it makes no sense except when you specialize everything explicitly.

Comment: Continued: templates do not belong to libraries (DLLs or static) at all. Libraries contain compiled code. Templates do not by themselves produce compiled code, only template specializations do.

Answer (score 0):

I find this post that might answer your question https://anteru.net/blog/2008/11/19/318/

Also I think this problem is because you did not instantiate your template in it's own dll.
One solution is define **child** class in the same dll as **base** class.
If this will break class and module's design, you could extract a class **A** that can be derived by **child**, and put **A** in the same dll as **base** class.