# undefined reference to `KDTree<Point>::points_'

Tags: c++

I'm getting this error " undefined reference to `KDTree<Point>::points_` "
here is my code:

```
template<class T>
std::list<Node<T> *> KDTree<T>::FindKNearestNeighbour(T key, int k) {
    assert(IsEmpty() == false);

    points_ = key; //(Error in this line)
    FindKNearestNeighbour(key, root_, 0, k);

    return nearestNs_;
}
```

`points_` is of type `T` and static variable.

if I change the line from `points_ = key` to `this->points_ = key` , I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Can you show us how and where you have defined your `points_`?

Comment: did you try `KDTree<T>::points_` ?

Comment: @vz_
template<class T>
class KDTree {
.
.
.// Functions 
.
public:
 Node<T> * root_;
 static T points_;
public:
 std::list<Node<T> *> nearestNs_;
 std::vector<Node<T> *> nearestWithDistance_;
};

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi yup i tried that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect, you forgot to initialize your static member. Look at this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2220990/2889345).

So put in your file

```
template<class T>
T KDTree<T>::points_;
```

and use `KDTree<T>::points_` in your function, because this member is a part of KDTree class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change `points_ = key;` to  `this->points_ = key;` then compile again. `points_` is a template member so it depends on template arguments `T`.