# Is this the correct way to initialize static data members of template classes?

Tags: c++

Is this the correct way to initialize static data members of template classes?

```
template <typename T>
class Temp
{
public:
    static unsigned int x;
};

template <typename T>
unsigned int Temp<T>::x = 0;
```

Comment: Well, does it work as expected?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ static template member, one instance for each template type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220975/c-static-template-member-one-instance-for-each-template-type)

Comment: @legends2k: They are quite obviously not the same question.

Comment: Well, then [these are](https://www.google.com/search?q=static+template+member)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Yes, it is.

> `[C++11: 14.5.1.3/1]` A definition for a static data member may be provided in a namespace scope enclosing the definition of the static member’s class template. *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> template<class T> class X {
>    static T s;
> };
>
> template<class T> T X<T>::s = 0;
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*